# Haxe Vector documentation?

Tags: haxe

I am looking for more information on the core functions of the haxe.ds package class Vector. Particularly, I am looking to find out what the available functions are, and what they actually do to the class (eg. add, remove, insert, pop, size).

So far, I have found:

https://haxe.org/manual/std-vector.html

and

https://api.haxe.org/haxe/ds/Vector.html

however neither offer me the information I am looking for. I have briefly and without success searched through haxe's github files in an attempt to find the ds package.

Any information on Vector documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad, there was a link to source in one of the links I posted above.

https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/3.4.7/std/haxe/ds/Vector.hx